# Ionic pop page not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am quite new to Ionic and I struggle to go back to the previous page.
Error Uncaught (in promise): navigation stack needs at least one root.
However in login(), I push the TabsPage above the root (LoginPage).
With pop() I would like to go back to LoginPage.

I would be glad if you could help.

Here is my code:

myApp.ts:

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = 'LoginPage';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

login.ts:

```
public login() { 
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
        this.nav.push(TabsPage);
      } else {
        this.showError("Email ou mot de passe incorrect");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }
```

tabs:

```
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = OrdersPage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ProfilePage;

  /**
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}
}
```

profile.ts:

```
    public logout(){
      this.auth.logout().subscribe(logedout => {
          if(logedout){
              this.navCtrl.pop();
          }
      });
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You talk about `TabsPage` but I don't see the code for it.

Comment: @Protectator Thanks for your answer. I updated my question

Comment: I see `tab3Root = ProfilePage;`. Does that mean you then set the root to `Profile` ? If yes, then it's the reason why you can't go back using `pop` : Profile is now the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is You are trying to pop from a tab root page. In Ionic Tabs, each tab is the root of its own navigation stack.
You will need to set `LoginPage` *as root* using the application NavController.

In profile.ts,

```
 import { App } from ionic-angular;


constructor(private app:App){}

public logout(){
  this.auth.logout().subscribe(logedout => {
      if(logedout){
          this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
      }
  });
}
```

**ALSO**, you need to set TabsPage as root from LoginPage to avoid user pressing back and getting back to Loginpage.

```
 if (allowed) {        
    this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);//here
  } else {
    this.showError("Email ou mot de passe incorrect");
  }
```